# How to make data available only to specific user in web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, architecture

This seems like it should be something often implemented, but I'm having hard time finding info.

I have Net Core MVC app which simply displays entries from DB(main.db). I want registered users to be able to edit/delete/whatever those entries for themselves.
And next time when user logs in, he sees that changed data. Of course other users see default, unchanged entries from main.db

[In documentation when one changes data, it changes for everyone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

What is the standard approach to implementing something like this? Somehow map "main.db" with AspNetUsers table from "identity_service.db"?

Comment: Please post what your current code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is authorization, which is a frontend thing. You don't and shouldn't restrict access to the DB on a user by user basis. Rather, you have just one DB user, which is what your app itself uses to fetch data. The ability to edit, delete, etc. is controlled by the app, based on whether the user is "authorized" for that particular operation or not, which is normally controlled via roles or claims.

In other words, you'd set up roles like `Edit`, `Delete`, etc. and then you assign those roles to users as appropriate: i.e. the ones who who should be able to edit, get the `Edit` role assigned.

Finally, you'll have one or more actions that actually present the view for editing: the user interacts with some form on an HTML page in order to actually make the edits. For these actions, you protect them via the `Authorize` attribute and specify the role(s) that are allowed:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Edit")]
public IActionResult MyEditAction()
```

If the user does not have the appropriate role(s), then they are denied access to that view, and thus cannot make the necessary interactions to affect an "edit".

This is intentionally a very basic overview. There's likely other types of authorization you will need to do: resource-based (AKA row-level), policy-based, etc. Consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more info.

Comment: But when one of the authorized users edits data, those edits happen to all users. 
My question is how to implement that they see different entries from db , depending on what they deleted/added

Comment: They'd have to have their own versions (copies) of those entities. In which case you're looking at resource-based authorization.